# how to save and restore camera configuration

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm rendering 3d models with PerspectiveCamera and TrackballControls, I don't know how to save and restore camera so that same view will be rendered after browser closed. 
While user can drag or scroll to adjust camera, how can I get the full data of camera, so that I can save to server, camera can be restore next time I see the model.
Please help me.

Comment: Study https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Client-side_storage. Then, edit your post and show what you have tried.

Comment: Thank u for your response. My question was bad. I've modified it. My point is what data to save, not where to save data.

Comment: Have you tried to save the properties [position](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D.position), [rotation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D.rotation) and [scale](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D.scale) of your camera?

Comment: @linzaihui Also save `camera.up` and `controls.target`.